# Unable to parse Twilio parameters

Tags: twilio

A Twilio beginner question: I have followed [these instructions](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-can-i-forward-recordings-to-my-email-inbox) to set up a simple voicemail system that emails a notification of the voicemail, including the number called from and a link to the recording. However I have been unable to get my code to parse the parameters that are supposedly sent by Twilio.

This is the Twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Record action="mail.php" />
</Response>
```

And this is the mail.php that it *actions* to:

```
<?php
/**
* This section ensures that Twilio gets a response.
*/
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<Response></Response>'; //Place the desired response (if any) here.
/**
* This section actually sends the email.
*/
$to = "your-email@example.com"; // Your email address.
$subject = "Message from {$_REQUEST['From']}";
$message = "You have received a message from {$_REQUEST['From']}.";
$message .= "To listen to this message, please visit this URL: {$_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']}";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com"; // Who should it come from?
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The voicemail is recorded and the email is sent, but the received email does not contain any values for the variables {$_REQUEST['From']} and {$_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']}, e.g. "You have received a message from . To listen to this message, please visit this URL: ."

Hopefully there is something obvious I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions would be most welcome. Thanks.